# ¿Cómo evitar que SQL Server omita espacios al final de una cadena?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, yo tengo la siguiente sentencia y necesito saber el largo total que tendría una variable tipo ***varchar*** a la cuál le asigno el valor de otra variable mas una cierta cantidad de espacios. Mi problema es que el sql server me "elimina" los espacios al final de la cadena y con el LEN solo obtengo el largo de la variable sin los espacios. ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que los tome en cuenta?

```
set @var1=(select @var2+'   ')
select len(@var1)
```

Comment: Estaba mal formulada mi pregunta, no se correspondía con lo que quería hacer realmente

Comment: En la anterior pedia el length de la cadena, aca inserto todo en una variable y luego pido el length de esa variable

Comment: @EzequielGómez, para efectos prácticos, no hay diferencia entre que pidas el largo de una variable o de una cadena.

Comment: Y para el caso, por como funciona el sitio, si la respuesta era valida y correcta deberias haberla aceptado, y si tenias otra duda, haber lanzado una nueva pregunta. No borrar la anterior

Answer (score 4):

Buen día, para que SQL Server no omita los espacios al final debe utilizar la funcion DATALENGTH, la sentencia quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
set @var1=(select @var2+'   ')
select DATALENGTH(@var1)
```

saludos

Comment: Esto no me funciona, estoy probando lo siguiente:
`declare @var1 varchar
declare @var2 varchar='a'

set @var1=(select @var2+'                   ')

select DATALENGTH(@var1)}`

Y el len me da resultado 1

Comment: @Ezequiel: Su respuesta sí funciona. Tu problema, que no se puede determinar por la información incompleta en la pregunta, es que estás declarando tu variable con `varchar` sin especificar un tamaño. Al no especificarlo, el tamaño es 1, por lo que está cortando los caracteres. Prueba declarando tus variables con `varchar(30)` o algo por el estilo y verás que funciona. De allí la importancia de que tu pregunta incluya siempre un verdadero [mcve].

Comment: No me habia dado cuenta de ese detalle. Gracias

Comment: Tambien podria probar de la siguiente manera: declare @var2 nvarchar='a '  select DATALENGTH(@var2);, declarando la variable como nvarchar

Comment: @Yeison: No, esa última opción es un error. Porque aunque te devuelva 2, no es porque está contando el espacio al final, sino porque está contando los 2 bytes que se requiere para representar el `a` con el tipo `nvarchar`. A evitar.

Answer (score 2):

Agrego otra opción para beneficio de otros lectores, por la razón de que, aunque el uso de `DATALENGTH` funciona en tu caso específico, en realidad no cumple la misma función que `LEN`, y esto puede causar problemas si el tipo de la variable no es siempre un `VARCHAR`.

Nota la diferencia entre las 2 funciones según se las define en la documentación oficial.

[`LEN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql):

> Devuelve el número de **caracteres** de la expresión de cadena especificada, excluidos los espacios en blanco finales.

[`DATALENGTH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql):

> Devuelve el número de **bytes** utilizados para representar cualquier expresión.

Con el tipo `VARCHAR`, esta diferencia no cambia nada, porque cada caracter es representado por un byte de todas maneras. Pero con el tipo `NVARCHAR` por ejemplo, entonces la diferencia es notable, porque cada caracter es representado por 2 bytes.

Por ejemplo, la expresión siguiente:

```
select DATALENGTH(N'abc')
```

... devuelve 6, no 3, porque aunque tenemos 3 caracteres, estos usan 6 bytes.

Aquí te dejo otra opción que funcionará correctamente sin importar que tu variable sea de tipo `VARCHAR` o `NVARCHAR`:

```
select LEN(@var1 + '.') - 1
```

La idea es que seguimos usando `LEN`, que cuenta caracteres, no bytes. Pero para evitar el problema de que no cuenta los espacios finales, le agregamos artificialmente un caracter al final, pero luego descontamos uno al resultado.